# nginx starting error with rails Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nginx, passenger

when i am trying to start nginx in my vps , it  is showing below error . I am using centos vps.

```
[sarath@vps111 ~]$ sudo service nginx restart
nginx: the configuration file /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf syntax is ok
nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Unable to start the Phusion Passenger helper agent: it seems to have crashed during startup for an unknown reason, with exit code 1 (-1: Unknown error)
nginx: configuration file /opt/nginx/conf/nginx.conf test is successful
Stopping nginx:                                            [  OK  ]
Starting nginx: nginx: [alert] Unable to start the Phusion Passenger watchdog because it encountered the following error during startup: Cannot create a Unix socket pair: Cannot allocate memory (errno=12) (-1: Unknown error)
```

Is this error is related to nginx , OS or hardware specific ? any solution ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Kill the service and then start it again.

```
$ ps -A | grep -i passenger | xargs kill -9
```

Try with sudo if you get errors.

Just in case this command is not working do:

```
$ kill -9 $(pgrep Passenger)
```

Usually I get this error when another instance is running.